# How can I get the user UUID using the JSON API?

Tags: 9

I tried the following JSON API query strings to get the UUID, but I keep getting a 404 error.

- `{url}/jsonapi/user/user?filter[uid][value]={uid}`
- `{url}/jsonapi/user/user/{uid}`
- `{url}/jsonapi/user/user?filter%5Banon%5D%5Bcondition%5D%5Bpath%5D=uid&filter%5Banon%5D%5Bcondition%5D%5Bvalue%5D=0&filter%5Banon%5D%5Bcondition%5D%5Boperator%5D=%3C%3E`

EDIT:

Forgot to include this route:
`{url}/user/{uid}`

Comment: Is /jsonapi/user/user a route?

Comment: I think that it is. What jsonapi setup have you done and what are you using to authenticate to the API?

Comment: It's set to Accept all JSON:API. In REST server settings User is enabled but the route it defines also doesn't work. EDIT: using basic_auth

Comment: I can't reproduce what you have reported. Is the jsonapi module enabled? Does *any* jsonapi route work on the site? Is only this route missing? What does `vendor/bin/drush route` show regarding jsonapi routes? Is see /jsonapi/user/user there, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused whether you want the UUID as suggested in the question title or the UID as suggested in your code.

### UID

By default, it's `drupal_internal__uid`, not `uid`.

You can confirm this by visiting `/jsonapi/user/user` and checking the output.

For example:

`https://example.ddev.site/jsonapi/user/user?&filter[drupal_internal__uid]=3`

If you want to shorten `drupal_internal__uid` to `uid`, you can install the [JSON:API Extras module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_extras) and configure an override for the User resource.

### UUID

In JSON:API, the UUID is always `id` regardless of what kind of entity you have:

`https://example.ddev.site/jsonapi/user/user?&filter[id]=2e5bcb94-574d-424b-98a7-2dd450c51a2c`

### Finding out the names of stuff in JSON:API

You can use the [JSON:API Explorer module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_explorer) to check out the JSON output visually.